# how to deploy Visual Studio Development Server with web applications

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, webdev.webserver

i want to know how do i deploy ASP.NET web applications on client machines which runs with the visual studio development server rather than configure it in the IIS on the client machine?
I know its possible and telerik also uses this approach.
any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't you simply install visual studio? Try googling for Cassini redistributable, but it doesn't seem to be available from Microsoft any more.

Comment: are you developing in ASP.NET 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deploy ASP.NET Application with WebServer](http://ultidev.com/products/cassini/CassiniRedistirbWithVS2005.htm)